# How to retrieve the Current Presenter in GWT or GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Here is my  problem. I have many links in my header presenter.

```
Link1 - Link2 - Link3 - GuideDialogLink
```

When user clicks on Link1 or Link2 or Link3, it will open a new browser.

However, when user clicks on GuideDialogLink, then it will popup a DialogBox right on top of the current link.

The GuideDialog is designed in a way that it show different Gui depending on which link user is staying. Its code is like this:

```
 class GuideDialog extends DialogBox{
    public GuideDialog(int whichLink){
       if(whichLink==0){
           //show Gui 1 
       }
       else if(whichLink==2){
           //show Gui 2 
       }
       else if(whichLink==3){
           //show Gui 3 
       }
    }
 }
```

Ex, when user is staying in Link3 & if they click GuideDialogLink, it will show a DialogBox that has Gui3 which is different from Gui1 or Gui2 if user is staying on Link1 or Link2.

So, my question is:

Is there any way to retrieve the Current Presenter?

If we know which Presenter is current one, then we can call GuideDialog accordingly ex: `GuideDialog myGD=new GuideDialog(0);`

-Other solution is to store a `public static int currentLink` in `Utility` class. And when user clicks link1 or link2 or link3 we can use EventBus to set `public static currentLink` to set accordingly & eventually `GuideDialog myGD=new GuideDialog(Utility.currentLink);`.

But i don't think this solution is elegant since Google must have some function to let us know which current page we are in.

So how can i solve my problem elegantly?

EDIT

Ok, let me clarify it. I am using GWTP to create my webapp.

-1st, I used eclipse to generate HeaderPresenter. The eclipse will create (HeaderPresenter.java, HeaderView.java & HeaderView.ui.xml). HeaderPresenter has 4 hyperlinks: link1,link2, link3, GuideDialogLink.

-2nd, I created Link1Presenter (Link1Presenter.java, Link1View.java, Link1View.ui.xml). Then i created Link2Presenter (Link2Presenter.java, Link2View.java, Link2View.ui.xml). Then I created Link3Presenter (Link3Presenter.java, Link3View.java, Link3View.ui.xml)

-3rd, I used `setInSlot` to make  Link1Presenter, Link2Presenter, Link3Presenter to be embeded or nested inside HeaderPresenter. It means when user go to link1 (ex: abc.com#link1) they will see 4 hyperlinks (link1,link2, link3, GuideDialogLink). If they go to link2  (ex: abc.com#link2) or link3, they also see 4 hyperlinks.

-4th, I create GuideDialog.java extends DialogBox & in the HeaderPresenter, i has `guideDialogLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){ GuideDialog myGD=new GuideDialog (int whichLink); });`

So when users are in either link1,2, or 3 they will see GuideDialogLink right? & when they click GuideDialog a DialogBox will popup right?

Now my requirement is that when users are in Link1 & if they click GuideDialogLink, a dialog will popup & show a Gui (2 textboxes on it). When users are in Link2 & if they click GuideDialogLink, a dialog will popup & show another Gui (2 labels on it). When users are in Link3 & if they click GuideDialogLink, a dialog will popup & show another different Gui (2 checkboxes on it)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, what you want is hovering over a link, then click on the show-dialog button, and the dialog will show the view associated with the correspondant presenter, is that right?

Comment: no, when user clicks on the GuideDialogLink, then a DialogBox will popup, it won't open new browser. So suppose u are in the link1 (my.com/link1) & u click on GuideDialogLink, then u are still in my.com/link1 & the dialogbox will show the Gui1 (say 1 button & 2 textbox). Ok now u are in my.com/link2 & u clicks GuideDialogLink, then u are still in my.com/link2 & the dialogbox will show the Gui2 (maby be there're 4 radio buttons + 2 labels)

Comment: So, the scenario is the following: we have 3 Views each associated with its corresponding presenter. Then we've got: Link1-View1-Presenter1, and so on. Then if you stay in Link1 view and then click on GuideDialogLink you will show some GUI retrieved by Presenter1. Is that correct?

Comment: thank u for ur question, yes, almost correct, but the Gui can be anything & not necessary from Presenter1, but the Gui is based on Presenter1. Ex, Presenter 1 is about Product, then the Gui is the Guideline of product. If the Presenter2 is about Service then the Gui of DialogBox could be Service  Guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have something like this:

**General views**

```
// defines what you can access from a View
interface GeneralDisplay extends Display {
}

// implements a View
class abstract GeneralView implements GeneralDisplay {

    // **Edit**: here you code the corresponding GUI
    public abstract Composite getDialogGUI();
}
```

**Link specific views**

```
// additional, if you need specific behavior in your linkX view
interface LinkDisplay1 extends GeneralDisplay {
}

// if all views are the same there's no need to implement LinkDisplayX
class LinkView1 extends GeneralView implements LinkDisplay1 {

    @Override
    public Composite getDialogGUI () {
        // **Edit** here you code the DialogGUI
    }
}

// other LinkViews ...
```

**Presenters**

```
// a more generic presenter for all Links
class GeneralPresenter<D extends GeneralDisplay> extends DefaultPresenter<D> {
    // some code here ...

    // constructor, here you associate the corresponding display
    public GeneralPresenter (D display, EventBus eventBus, DispatchAsync dispatch) {
        super(display,eventBus,dispatch);  
        // some code here ...
    }

    public void onBind () {
        registerHandler(display.getDialogBoxLink().addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler () {
             doShowDialogGUI();
        }));
    }

    public void doShowDialogGUI () {
        // here you show the dialog box, you can access the corresponding view by:          
        // this.display
        // **Edit** add some code here
        display.getDialogBox().setWidget(display.getDialogGUI());

    }

}

// Then you have the follogiwng
class LinkPresenter1<D extends GeneralDisplay> extends GeneralPresenter<D> {
    // some code here ...

    @Override 
    public void onBind () {
        super.onBind(); // here is where the "real stuff" is binded
    }
}
```

For further information you can read [GWT-MVP (Model-View-Presenter, a variant from MVC) architecture](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html), this is an excellent piece of information which shows you how the MVP architecture works.

**Edit: ** I have added some extra pieces of code for retrieving corresponding DialogGUIs views.

Comment: i am using GWTP & eclipse so eclipse will create all necessary classes for me when I am create a presenter. Ex, when creating HeaderPresenter, it will create HeaderPresenter.java, HeaderView.java & HeaderView.ui.xml. When creating Link1Presenter it will create Link1Presenter.java, Link1View.jav, Link1View.ui.xml

Comment: Oh, alright, so you've got all the neccesary structure concerning the MVP pattern. But, I think you have to add an extra layer of abstraction, cause you need to perform a generic click over a link and return the corresponding DialogView. That's why I added the extra GenericDisplay, View and Presenter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem:

When you click on a link, your place changes (PlaceTokenizer, controller ect...). So the information is in the PlaceController (current place url).

You can grab the info from there. If you have a ClientFactory, you can get the PlaceController from it and ask which is the current Place object.

For example :

```
public P getCurrentPlace() {
    return (P) commonClientFactory.getPlaceController().getWhere();
}
```

### ...

**Note:** 
The info is also in the ActivityManager (which I don't recommend to use in your case, since you're interested in a bigger scope (the place), and not: the current Activity )

Comment: Ok, i have a headerpresenter which has link1,2,3 & GuideDialogLink. When user clicks on link1 it will open Link1Presenter (my.com/#!link1) & when users are in link1 they still see 4 links cos link1 is nested inside the headerpresenter, & when on link1 if user click on GuideDialogLink , then a dialogbox will popup. When they in link2 they also see 4 links since links was nested inside HeaderPresenter & when user clicks on GuideDialogBo, then a dialogbox will popup but this time the Gui on the dialogbox is different from when users are in link1

Comment: Ok so you need to open the popup depending on the selected link (my.com/#!link1 or my.com/#!link3 let's say). So you only need to get the current Place object, and read which link is the currently selected.

If your problem is only to keep the popup open, you can have a boolean in your activity which says if the popup is open. If true, open immediately the popup on display (this needs a small hack in ActivityManager which skips Activity.start() if the same activity is returned by the ActivityMapper)

Anyway, I suggest you do all your work based on the url, otherwise prblm on url copy-paste

Comment: So to recapitulate:
1- add a boolean to your Presenter (Activity) to know if the popup is open (eventually add it to the place)
2- Hack ActivityManager so it calls start() or add a method refresh() if the Activity returned by the mapper is the same
3- Check the boolean + url and decide on dialog content and state

Comment: in my HeaderPresenter, i have myGuideLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){ GuideDialog gD=new GuideDialog }); so how we can know which link is currently exsting  when we open DialogBox. i think it should have a simpler solution.

Comment: i got it, so simple just use placeManager & it can do magic things, see my answer. Thax u anyway, cos ur answer help me to find a right solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers, very simple.

1st, when opening a new link we can add a param like whichLink. Ex `my.com#link1;whichLink=link1`

Then in HeaderPresenter, when calling GuideDialog, we do this

```
GuideDialogBox gDialogBox=new GuideDialogBox(placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest().getParameter("whichLink", "home"));
```